# Visual studio 2017 Breakpoint does not trigger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS2017 with .NET Core and the code that I am trying to debug is written in C# so its pretty simple set up.

Now, I have not had this issue before ever in my life. However, it sounds like today is special. I did put a break-point at one of the lines and VS executes that line but does not stop at the break point that I did put there.

I really want to be able to give more info but there is literally nothing more to the problem. Any ideas on why it could be happening?

Comment: Are you running a debug build? How do you know that line actually executes? Have you tried setting a breakpoint somewhere above that point to see if it stops there? Can you set breakpoints at other places in your code that actually trigger, or do breakpoints just not work at all? Not enough info here. You're saying *My car doesn't work. What's wrong?*, and the mechanic needs much more information before they can answer.

Comment: Ok. I should had been more clear. I did put multiple breakpoints including the starting point of the application. It does execute the application(all the 10 lines of code where break point is set). Anyways, I found the solution from you comments. I was running Visual studio solution in `release` mod instead of `Debug` mode

Comment: OK. Voting to close it as *a problem that can't be reproduced*, as it's a simple case of trying to debug a non-debugging build. You may want to delete it.

Comment: @TeaLeave, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, but if possible, you could share the solution as an answer and mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. It turned out that I was running visual studio in `release` mode instead of `Debug` mode. Changing the mode to `debug` resolved the issue